# Prove the relation is an equivalence relation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, relations

## Problem

> Define the relation $R$ on the set of natural numbers as $(a,b) \in R
> > \iff 2 \vert(a^2 + b) $. Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

---

This is what I have so far.

### Claim:

Define the relation $R$ on the set of natural numbers as $(a,b) \in R
> \iff 2 \mid(a^2 + b) $. The relation $R$ is an equivalence relation.

### Proof:

**Part 1 (Reflixivity):**

Let $R = \{(a,b) \in \Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N} \mid 2 \mid (a^2+b)\}$ be given and suppose that $b \in \Bbb{N}$.

Then, for some integer $k$:

$$\require{enclose}
\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{\begin{align}
2 \mid b^2 +b \iff 2k &= b^2 +b \\
 & = b^2 + b - (b^2 + b) + (b^2 + b) \\ 
 & = 2b^2 + 2b - (b^2 + b) \\ 
 & = -2b^2 - 2b + (b^2 + b)
\end{align}}$$

Therefore, 
$$\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{\begin{align}
2 \mid b^2 +b \iff b^2 + b &= 2k -2b^2 - 2b \\
 & = 2(k - b^2 - b)\\  
 & 
\end{align}}$$

$\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{Thus, $2 \mid b^2 +b$ for some integer $(k - b^2 - b)$. Which implies that $R$ is Reflexive.}} $

> **EDIT:** Thanks to some positive feed back I have been let known that this is not showing Reflexivity.

**Part 2 (Symmetry)**

Let $R = \{(a,b) \in \Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N} \mid 2 \mid (a^2+b)\}$ be given and suppose that, for any $a,b \in \Bbb{N}$, $ a\mathbf{R}b \leftrightarrow b\mathbf{R}a.$ 
Then, for some integer $k$:

$$\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\begin{align}
2 \mid a^2 + b  & \iff 2k = a^2 + b \\
 & \iff 2k + (a + b^2) = (a^2 + b) + (a + b^2)\\ 
 & \iff (a + b^2) = (a + b) + (a^2 + b^2) - 2k \\ 
 & 
\end{align}}$$

$\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{Since, the relation $R$ is proven to be Reflexive, let the integer $ m = a = b $ and let the integer $ n = a^2 = b^2 $. Then, }}$

> **EDIT:** This is not a valid way to show Symmetry, since **Part 1 (Reflexivity)** has not been proven.

$$\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\begin{align}
a + b^2 = (a + b) + (a^2 + b^2) - 2k & \iff (a + b^2) = 2m + 2n - 2k \\
 & \iff (a + b^2) = 2(m + n -k)\\  
 & 
\end{align}}$$

$\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{Thus, $2 \mid b^2 + a$ which implies that $R$ is Symmetric since $ a\mathbf{R}b \leftrightarrow b\mathbf{R}a $.}}$

**Part 3 (Transitivity)**

Let $R = \{(a,b) \in \Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N} \mid 2 \mid (a^2+b)\}$ be given and suppose that, for any $a,b,c \in \Bbb{N}$, $ a\mathbf{R}b \text{ and } b\mathbf{R}c.$ Then, let $k$ and $h$ be some integers:

\begin{align}
2k = a^2 + b \text{ and } 2h = b^2 + c & \implies 2(k + h) = (a^2 + b) + (b^2 + c) \\
 & \\ 
 & \\ 
 & 
\end{align}

> **Comment:** And, this is where I get stuck. I am struggling to find a way to show that $ (2 \mid a^2 + b) \land (2 \mid b^2 + c) \implies 2 \mid a^2 + c$. I've also tried eliminating $b$ like so, $2h = (2k - a^2)^2 + c$, but this doesn't seem to get me any where. I feel like I'm running in circles here.

## My Question

Can you argue that $R$ is transitive since it has already been shown that $2 \mid b^2 + b$?

This would imply something like "$2(k - b^2 - b) + 2h = (a^2 + c) +(b^2 + b)$ is logically equivalent to $(2 \mid b^2 + b) \land (2 \mid a^2 + c)$." And, this simplifies to just $2 \mid a^2 + c$ by the inference rule of simplification [$(p \land q) \to p$]. Which ultimatily I believe gets me to my goal, but I'm not sure if it is two far of a leep to go from $2(k - b^2 - b) + 2h = (a^2 + c) +(b^2 + b) \implies (2 \mid b^2 + b) \land (2 \mid a^2 + c)$.

I hope my question was specific enough. Otherwise, I would much appreciate some guidance on showing how this relation is transitive if anyone is feeling generous. Thanks!

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but see your professor.  You have fundamental misunderstandings of the basics.  You don't seem to understand the difference between *stating* that a condition is required and *showing* that the statement is actually true.  You state that if $2|b^2 + b$ then $2k = b^2 +b$ but seem to think that you have actually *shown* $2k = b^2 + b$.  I do not think there is anything salvageable in this proof or anything worth fixing.

Comment: Yes, I am not taking this wrong way. Thank you for the feedback. I did feel like I was running in a circle on showing that $2|b^2 + b$. In fact, I felt like I was running in a giant circle on this entire problem. And, technically I was unable to show that the relation was symmetric since it hinges on the fact that the reflexivity of the relation has already been proven (which it wasn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is too technical.

Note that $$2| (a^2 + b)$$ if and only if both $a$ and $b$ are odd or both are even.

Reflexivity: $a$ and $a^2$ are either both even or both odd.

Symmetry: If both $a$ and $b$ are odd then both $b$ and $a$ are also odd. Similarly for the even case.

Transitivity: If $a$ and $b$ are related and $b$ and $c$ are related then all three of them are odd or all three are even .

In any case a and c are both odd or both even.

Comment: I'll take note of that. I also notice that part of your approach is to find some sort of reason of "where, why, and when" $2| (a^2 + b)$ is true. My book states that, "partitions and equivalence relations are essentially the same thing." Is it true to say that you are looking to see how the relation could be partitioning the set of natural numbers? And, then you go on to use that as the basis of your proof. I appreciate your feedback. Thank you!

Comment: @Jordan  you are correct. The partitioning is the parity classes. We divide the natural numbers into odds and evens. One class is for odds, the other class is for evens. the relations is being in the same class.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. So, hypothetically, if the relation failed to be reflexive, symmetric, or transitive, then there would be some even number for $a$ and some odd number for $b$ where the statement $2| (a^2 + b)$ is true? I guess, you could say that when you put all of these three properties together they effectively make some partition exist. It is not that this only works because $a$ and $b$ both _just happen_ to be odd numbers. It is that it _can only ever work_ if $a$ and $b$ are both odd numbers. And, likewise for if they are even numbers.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: Would you need to prove that it is an equivalence relation in both cases of $a$ and $b$ both being odd, and of $a$ and $b$ both being even? Or, is it enough to prove that it is an equivalence relation by only using one case, lets say $a$ and $b$ both being even numbers for instance? (Sorry for asking you so many questions)

Answer (score 1):

If $2\mid a^2+b$ and $2\mid b^2+c$, then $2\mid a^2+b+b^2+c$. But $b+b^2=b(b+1)$, which is the product of two consecutive natural numbers, and therefore it's an even number. So, since $2\mid a^2+b+b^2+c$ and since $2\mid b^2+b$, $2\mid a^2+c$.